# Stata: Scale x variable by lagged y variable

Tags: stata

I'm trying to scale one variable by another lagged variable.

(IB) scaled by the lagged total assets(AT) = ROA

I've tried this two methods below from [here](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1426451-panel-data-using-lagged-variable).

```
xtset companyid fyear, year
gen at1 = l.at
gen roa=ib/at1
```

and

```
xtset gvkey year
gen roa=(ib)/(at[_n-1])
```

The first one came back with all zeros for 1.ta

The second one seems to generate values on the previous entry, even if it's a different company. I think this is true because only the first row has a missing value. I would assume there should be a missing value for the first year of each company.

Additionally I've tried this code below but it said invalid syntax.

```
xtset gvkey year
foreach gvkey { 
gen roa = (ib)/(at[_n-1]) }
```

I'm using compustat so it's similar to below:

```
  gvkey|Year |Ticker  | at   | ib   |
-------|-----|--------|------|------|
 001111| 2006| abc    |1000  |50    |
 001111| 2007| abc    |1100  |60    |
 001111| 2008| abc    |1200  |70    |
 001111| 2009| abc    |1300  |80    |
 001112| 2008| www    |28777 |1300  |
 001112| 2009| www    |26123 |870   |
 001113| 2009| ttt    |550   |-1000 |
 001114| 2010| vvv    |551   |-990  |
```

Comment: The Statalist thread you're citing explains exactly why the second approach is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to follow. `1.ta` may, or may not, be a typo for `L.at`.

Is `gvkey` string? At the Stata tag, there is really detailed advice about how to give Stata data examples, which you are not following.

In principle, your first approach is correct, so it is hard to know what went wrong, except that

1. > The second one seems to `generate` values on the previous entry, even if
   >   it's a different company.

That's exactly correct. The previous observation is the previous observation, and nothing in that command refers or alludes to the panel structure or `xtset` or `tsset` information.

2. Your `foreach` statement is just wild guessing and nothing to do with any form supported by `foreach`. `foreach` isn't needed here at all: the lag operator implies working within panels automatically.

I did this, which may help.

```
clear 
input str6 gvkey Year  str3 Ticker   at    ib   
 001111 2006 abc    1000  50    
 001111 2007 abc    1100  60    
 001111 2008 abc    1200  70    
 001111 2009 abc    1300  80    
 001112 2008 www    28777 1300  
 001112 2009 www    26123 870   
 001113 2009 ttt    550   -1000 
 001114 2010 vvv    551   -990  
end 

egen id = group(gvkey), label 
xtset id Year 

gen wanted = at/L.ib 

list, sepby(gvkey) 

     +------------------------------------------------------------+
     |  gvkey   Year   Ticker      at      ib       id     wanted |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 001111   2006      abc    1000      50   001111          . |
  2. | 001111   2007      abc    1100      60   001111         22 |
  3. | 001111   2008      abc    1200      70   001111         20 |
  4. | 001111   2009      abc    1300      80   001111   18.57143 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  5. | 001112   2008      www   28777    1300   001112          . |
  6. | 001112   2009      www   26123     870   001112   20.09462 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  7. | 001113   2009      ttt     550   -1000   001113          . |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  8. | 001114   2010      vvv     551    -990   001114          . |
     +------------------------------------------------------------+
```